# MAC connected to WIFI but not able to browse internet (issue started after connecting to VPN)

Tags: macos, dns, vpn

I am using MAC for the first time

1. I have connected to my home WIFI and am able to browse the internet successfully
2. I connected to a VPN(OpenVPN) and am able to browse the internet successfully
3. I have shut down my MAC(without disconnecting the VPN) and started it later. From then onwards, I am connected to WIFI but the internet is not working (If I login into the Guest account on MAC then I am able to browse the internet successfully. But in Guest account I can only use the Safari so I am not able to see the default DNS entries in system preferences)

I think that the VPN has changed the DNS entries and did not reset them so this is causing the problem.

How do I solve this issue? I restarted the MAC but it did not resolve the issue

How to reset the DNS entries to the default state (not the DNS cache but the DNS entries itself)?

Comment: not sure why this question was downvoted. When I tried to search for an answer to this question, every search result showed that flushing DNS cache was the answer which was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `system preferences->Network->WIFI->Advanced->DNS`

Delete all the entries(using minus icon) in DNS servers and search domains. Then MAC will populate the default ones automatically

P.S:
The below commands will **not** solve the problem for this case,

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```